# Number of dimensions for each word vector in a given model 'en' is 0

Tags: nlp, spacy, word2vec

I want to print the number of dimensions for each word vector from the spacy language model 'en'. I installed both the language model and spacy. I have following lines of code

```
import spacy
nlp =spacy.load('en')
dim = nlp.vocab.vectors_length
print(dim)
```

It gives 0.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hi Manoj, welcome to stack overflow - good first question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `en` model doesn't include word vectors. You should use the `en_core_web_md` or `en_core_web_lg` models instead, which do.